# Do we want web-series on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

**Warning!! Poor examples ahead!!!!**

- [Day[9] Daily](http://blip.tv/day9tv)
- [The Guild](http://www.watchtheguild.com/)
- [Journey Quest](http://www.journey-quest.com/)
- [Pioneer One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_One)
- [Mortal Kombat : Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat:_Legacy)
- [Daredevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(TV_series))
- [Hemlock Grove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemlock_Grove_(TV_series))

Among other series are popular web-only series that air on a regular schedule, with each episode archived for later on-demand viewing.

Do we want questions about Web-Only series on M&TV.SE, even though technically these aren't *TV Series* but *Web Series*?

(again note, my examples are poor as there aren't really many questions you can get out of these series nor do I know of many web series, but I'm sure everyone here gets the point.)

Comment: If anyone else has better examples, please edit them in as I'm at a loss.

Comment: zombieorpheus.com has a lot of web series (journey quest probably being their most popular).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would say that as long as they are professionally produced there shouldn't be made a difference between TV and web series (or movies) on this site.

It is very likely that the borders between television and the internet will blur in the upcoming years, so eventually it will probably become impossible to exclude web stuff anyway.

The threshold of originality and professionality should be more important than the way of distribution, if you ask me. We should just make sure we don't end up getting questions about every youtube videblog out there.

**TLDR: Allow them as long as they are produced above amateur level.**

Comment: +1 agree, which is why I linked those examples.  One is a single-man show with decent production values that is pure sports-like analysis while the other is a group dedicated to creating a series with high production values.  That is what really counts.  I do agree that just some random YT vlog should not count.

Answer (score 6):

One needs to answer, *What is so different about them that would warrant exclusion*? My answer is *Nothing*. If it feels like dirtying the site, there aren't too many the anyways, as you mention. I just don't know if it's worth mentioning in the FAQ though.

Comment: Whether we mention it in the [faq] or not is irrelevant.  It's more of a "Hey, I just thought of this, would you guys agree this is ok?'

Answer (score 1):

Many TV series have Webisodes (Doctor How and Battlestar Galactica spring to mind). I don't see why they shouldn't be included.

Comment: Web-series is already being considered ON-Topic year ago.