# Why don't we add some old usefull meta post rather then keeping Community Bulletin empty?

Tags: discussion

These days we are having very less or no meta activity. So Community Bulletin is mostly empty (except existing SE blog). So why don't we add some old useful meta post which are less popular or add some from active posts.

Like [Do we want web-series on-topic here?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/do-we-want-web-series-on-topic-here). *-Just an example*

Comment: *"Just an example"* - Or maybe [Why don't we add some old usefull meta post rather then keeping Community Bulletin empty?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1086/49) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding of how the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag works is correct, mods can add the  tag to questions they want to feature on the community bulletin board:

> A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the main site in a special sidebar in the questions list and when viewing individual questions.

This will be up to the mods to maintain however.

Comment: Didn't know this feature previously. Thanks for informing.