# Is "the Homestar Runner series of animated Flash web cartoons" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a question about a joke on Strong Bad, which is apparently part of "the Homestar Runner series of animated Flash web cartoons" (quoting Wikipedia here): [Why does Strong Bad say April Fools was ruined on Feb 7, 2008?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77879/why-does-strong-bad-say-april-fools-was-ruined-on-feb-7-2008)

Can we really regard this as a "TV series"? Does this fall into this category: [Do we want web-series on-topic here?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/do-we-want-web-series-on-topic-here) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite the linked actual question **quality** (and I think it deserves to be closed) the answer to *this* Meta question is...
..

## YES

The first bullet point of our on-topic list is:

> - Analysis of content or theme of **all forms** of Movies and TV series

So webseries, youtube series etc. would seem to be on-topic to me. How the content is distributed isn't really relevant to its topicality.

That said, regardless of *how* it's distributed doesn't absolve it from being off-topic for **other** reasons which seems to be the case with the question that prompted this Meta post.

Comment: Fully agreed +1