# Does this site cover Youtube?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question about a given Youtube account/personality, is this site appropriate for that?

Example:

> In which Angry Grandpa video does Grandpa yell at Tina for eating all the ham before they have company over?

Since it's not technically TV or Movie, I'm not sure if this is appropriate. Is it worth proposing as a new site in Area51?

Comment: you're example i believe would already be off-topic not because youtube but because it's an Identification Request (Episode Identification is classified as an ID Request)

Comment: @Memor-X Where is that rule written? I don't see it here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: for id requests [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and about episode id requests see [this comment](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions#comment13131_4087) *"identification question in the sense of this policy (and the sense it has been used and discussed over the last years) means questions asking to identify a movie, TV-show, TV-show episode, or actor"*

Comment: remember this is ofcause based off your example which is off-topic for another reason which is unrelated to youtube

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Comment: Note that more technical questions about Youtube's functions may be on-topic on [Web Applications.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we do cover somewhat professionally produced webseries with narrative content similar to any other TV-show, we can't really cover every random internet dude's YouTube vlogs as that would end up heavily detracting from the site's idea of discussing films and TV-series. This has been touched upon in [this related discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/49) already.

Besides that, identification questions as well as technical questions about the workings of YouTube are off-topic, too. We're not YouTube's support forum either.

Comment: The linked discussion says "Allow them as long as they are produced above amateur level" - but that's really confusing because some YouTubers get paid for their work via either Patreon or YouTube's "Sponsor" button.  Many of these people have "making YouTube videos" as their full-time jobs.  Are they "professionals" or "amateurs?"